# flutter splash screen not working after update

Tags: android, flutter

I am facing a strange problem. I had a splash screen to my app ex. black in the background. But I change to a new splash screen to a white background.

- I changed all images in `android/app/res` folder.

Now the problem is the first slash screen still appear for a moment and after that second white screen will display.

- I tried flutter clean.
- deleting an app from mobile
- trying to run on different devices
- checked complete project folder for old splash screen it's not there.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Send me ur code  After i wiil check

Comment: @sureshmadaparthi which code? There is no separate code for splash screen.

Comment: Send me splash screen code

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" /> -->

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/splash" />
    </item>
</layer-list>`

Comment: this code xml or not

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash">


</RelativeLayout>

Comment: hello tell me clearly what u want

Comment: you can follow my tutorial : https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-splash-screen-9f4e05542548

Comment: @diegoveloper with your tutorial had the same problem. the old splash screen appears for fraction of sec.

Comment: could you add a gif or video to your question, to check the issue

Comment: @diegoveloper please check screen now. The first black splash screen is no more in app. I replace the same with second one.

Comment: Could you add your code? are you using splash screen from native code or from Dart?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen --> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <!-- <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" /> --> <!-- You can insert your own image assets here --> <item> <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@mipmap/splash" /> </item> </layer-list> `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183534/discussion-between-diegoveloper-and-prashant-fepale).